# How to create another column in pandas based on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns - Punchout and Contract.
I want a catalog flag column where it is FALSE if Punchout and Contract both are NAN otherwise it is TRUE.
I wrote the following piece of code:

```
req_line['Catalog_Flag'] = np.where((req_line['Contract']) & (req_line['Punchout']) = '[]',False,True)
```

but the error it throws is : `SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?`

Is there any other way also? Please help!

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
Contract | Punchout | Flag
NaN      | NaN      | False
NaN      | Computer Information | True
Non-CLM0_Cat_01 | NaN | True
```

Comment: Do you try `==` ? Can you add some sample data?

Comment: Yes, I did try that. Editing the question and adding sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here `np.where` is not necessary, just use `~` for invert mask with [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
req_line['Catalog_Flag'] = ~(req_line['Contract'].isna() & req_line['Punchout'].isna())
```

Working like test if no missing values with `|` for bitwise `OR` by [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html):

```
req_line['Catalog_Flag'] = req_line['Contract'].notna() | req_line['Punchout'].notna()

print (req_line)
          Contract              Punchout   Flag  Catalog_Flag
0              NaN                   NaN  False         False
1              NaN  Computer Information   True          True
2  Non-CLM0_Cat_01                   NaN   True          True
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) for identifying `nan`:

```
req_line['Catalog_Flag'] = np.where(req_line['Contract'].isna() & req_line['Punchout'].isna(), False, True)
```